# PHP to get the video id (or video url if possible) in certain playlist

Tags: php, youtube-api

I've found a code in the internet like this :

```
<?php
$api_key = "MY_API_KEY";
$playlist_id = "MY_PLAYLIST_ID";
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId='. $playlist_id . '&key=' . $api_key;
      
$playlist = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($playlist->items AS $item): ?>
  <li><img src="<?php echo $item->snippet->thumbnails->default->url; ?>"> <h4><?php echo $item->snippet->title;  ?></h4></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The code runs well and the result show a list of images and it's title.

Since I want the list to also have the video id (or video URL if possible),
what I've tried so far, between the `<li></li>` tag, I add a line like below:

```
<h4><?php echo $item->id->videoId;  ?></h4>
```

but it doesn't work, since the page result didn't shot the video id. And when I inspect the page, there is nothing in between of the addition `<h4></h4>` tag.

How do I have to code to get the video id ? (or maybe the url of the video if possible) ?

Comment: Have you checked the json structure? Does it even have an object named `id`?

Comment: Would it not be `$item->snippet->videoId`?

Comment: @mulquin, I've tried it but it didn't display the id. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Gil, I am sorry as I don't know how to see json structure.
Anyway, for the time being my solution is using the thumbnail URL as it contains the video id. Something like this `$id = $item->snippet->thumbnails->default->url; 
$id = str_replace('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/', '', $id);`. Thank you Gil.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification of the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint, the [JSON response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response) provided upon a call of it is formed by an array of [PlaylistItem objects](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource-representation):

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "videoOwnerChannelTitle": string,
    "videoOwnerChannelId": string,
    "playlistId": string,
    "position": unsigned integer,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": string,
      "videoId": string,
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": string,
    "startAt": string,
    "endAt": string,
    "note": string,
    "videoPublishedAt": datetime
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": string
  }
}
```

Now, it should be clear that the path to the video ID is:

```json
items[].snippet.resourceId.videoId
```

Translated to PHP that should be:

```php
$item->snippet->resourceId->videoId
```